# FreeMarker With Eclipse Luna

Tags: freemarker, eclipse-luna

I am currently trying to set Eclipse Luna for FreeMarker. I have installed FreeMarker IDE which is provided by JBoss : http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/

When I create and edit an FTL file, the syntax is highlighted, however the auto-completion and the syntax error indicator doesn't work.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: That plugin is so bad, it keeps causing assertion failure in eclipse

Comment: It is true, it is still unstable. Actually I don't use plugin at all because I keep my template simple. 

Anyway, if you really want a plugin in order to edit ftl you can choose an other ide or text editor. Here is the official link from freemarker : http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/editors.html

You can also help to improve freemarker eclipse plugin at this address : https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker

Comment: I was able to revert back to the 1.3 version. Even though it doesn't have the latest freemarker built-in vars but at least I can use the editor. This bug has been brought up before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also using Luna with that plugin, and those work for me (and always did). OTOH the whole plugin is so unstable, it's almost unusable (pops up error windows, goes out of sync with actual file content, etc.), but those has certainly nothing to do with Luna.

Edit : See the following comments to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I uninstalled the Freemarker plugin: `Help` -> `Installation Details` -> search for and select freemarker plugin -> `Uninstall...` . And then I associated *.ftl files with the xml editor and xml content type.

Comment: BTW, there's some activity around this: https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-18244. So there's some hope that these will be fixed.

Comment: I seemed to have (maybe) fixed most of the issues by copying the `freemarker-2.3.22.jar` into the freemarker plugin dir (where `freemarker-2.3.21.jar` is), then editing `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to reference the newer jar.

Comment: I did use the plugin with 2.3.22, but it wasn't more stable. It would be surprising if the FreeMarker version matters, since the plugin doesn't rely on FreeMarker much, it just uses it for the error markers.

Comment: Seems that many of the instability issues were fixed in JBoss Tools 4.3.0.Beta1! Though it's for Eclipse Mars, not Luna.

Comment: ddekany is correct. I've installed 1.4.101.Beta2 in Luna and haven't had any issues. I had to compile from source and manually add it. I hope they make a Luna release with these fixes.

Comment: It's ok for me. Thank you @ddekany  !

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for Spring Tools Suite. Hope it will work for others version of eclipse.

First Go Windows> Preference> then follow this image:

[image]

Second again go Windows> Preference> then follow this image:

[image]

then restart eclipse and re open .ftl file.
wish a good luck.